# How to add a "Actions List" in a Sharepoint Pop Up?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, popup

I have a PopUp opened by

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog
```

that contains a form, and I want it has some actions like a normal edit pop up (View Snapshot).

The pop ups content comes from a myPage.aspx (where I put the inputs and other stuff), and I want to add "the blue part", but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: the actions are called Ribbons :-)

Comment: Indeed, what you refer to is known as The Ribbon, or the "Fluent UI" as some call it. What buttons do you need to have? They are "context aware" and will appear depending on what things are on the page you're displaying.

Comment: Well, for my webpart I need the buttons Save, Cancel and Delete, but I think that if appears the other buttons (like the snapshot) there isn't any problems.

Comment: Here's an example that adds a custom action in the Edit Form: http://asreeharsha.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/add-a-button-as-a-ribbon-control-on-item-edit-form/